# Solve $x/(4x^2+1) = \tan(6x)$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$
\frac{x}{4x^2+1} = \tan(6x)
$$

Can this equation be solved for $x$ algebraically and can I get exact answer for this question? Or do I have to approximate it?

Comment: The trivial solution is $x=0$, I think you'll have to numerically evaluate all else.

Comment: Note too that $y=0$ is a horizontal asymptote for the LHS as $x\to\pm\infty$. This means that the solutions approach the zeroes of the RHS as $x$ grows large (positive or negative). That is, the solutions are approximately $\pm\pi k/6$ for large integral $k$. The approximation won't be as good for smaller $k$.

Comment: That's a very insightful comment! I tried the equation out on WolframAlpha and the values were 0 and approximately 0.564, 1.079, 1.594, and so on. It is quite close to pi/6 which is about 0.524.